# Print Out Rows Based on Condition

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'sport' : ['football', 'hockey', 'baseball', 'basketball'], 'league': ['NFL', 'NHL', 'MLB', 'NBA'], 'number': [1,2,3,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df

if df['number'] >= 3:
    print(df['number'])
```

I am attempting to print out some rows of this data frame where the number column is greater or equal to 3.  This should print out the last two rows in this particular example.  What is wrong in my approach?  I have tried `if df['number'] >= 3: print(df['number'])` as noted above.

Upon suggestion, the following code prints out the rows.  How would I only return columns `sport` and `number` (instead of all columns)?
[image]

Comment: This shows all rows.  How would I only return the ```sport``` and ```number``` columns? @Quang Hoang

Comment: You've asked two basic questions in a row. Please read the [documentations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case do

```
print(df.loc[df['number'] >= 3,['sport', 'number']])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following and it should print the rows with the matching values:

```
print(df[df['number'] >= 3])
```

or

```
print(df.loc[df['number'] >=3])
```

Saw your new comment. Here's how you would get the specific columns:

```
subset = df.loc[df['number'] >= 3]
print(subset[['sport', 'number']])
```

I used subset as another dataframe as it would hopefully be easier to manage and understand.

Comment: This shows all rows.  How would I only return the ```sport``` and ```number``` columns? @jp207

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, try,

```
df.loc[df['number'] >= 3, ['sport', 'number']]
```

Output:

```
        sport  number
2    baseball       3
3  basketball       4
```

A two-column dataframe where rows meet number condition.  Using column filtering via a list of column headers.